# Why are affine connections not induced from the smooth structure of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, smooth-manifolds

My understanding of affine connections is they hold the "second-order derivative" information of a manifold, while the equipped atlas holds the "first-order derivative" information. I would think that given a smooth atlas, it would induce an affine connection, or some way of talking about second-order derivative information i.e. a way to take the "second derivative" of a curve. However, we have to again equip the manifold with another structure, which is the affine connection.

Comment: A smooth structure does provide a way to talk about second derivatives: google for "bundle of jets". A connection is quite a different beast — it does allow you to think about second derivatives because it allows you to compare first derivatives are different points, but this cannot be done in a natural way (manifolds do not have natural connections; this should be proved in *Natural operations in differential geometry* by Ivan Kolář et al.

Comment: Can you show me where in that book it is proven? I would love to know why manifolds don't "have natural connections".

Comment: I don't have the book at hand, so I can't tell you, but it should be there. Surely the index has to be of help!

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf. I tried looking for a proof but I do not know a good keyword to look up. I tried browsing through the chapters with "connection" in their title, but haven't found anything yet. I'm really curious to read about it!